# Trigonometric equation $\sin{u}-\sin{2u}=1-2\cos{u}$

Tags: trigonometry

Spent a few hours today trying to solve it.

Find all solutions to the equation in the interval $[0,2\pi]$:

$$\sin{u}-\sin{2u}=1-2\cos{u}$$

Comment: You have not shown any work on the subject : this is why there are downvotes.

Comment: A general advise : plot the corresponding curves, here of functions $f(u)=\sin{u}-\sin{2u}$ and $g(u)=1-2\cos{u}$ to see for which values of $u$ they intersect...

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
0 &= \sin(u) - \sin(2u) - 1 + 2 \cos(u)  \\
  &= \sin(u) - 2\sin(u)\cos(u) - 1 + 2 \cos(u)  \\
  &= (1 - 2 \cos(u))\sin(u) - (1 - 2 \cos(u))  \\
  &= (1 - 2 \cos(u))(\sin(u) - 1)
\end{align*}
so either $1 - 2 \cos(u) = 0$ or $\sin(u) - 1 = 0$ (or both).  In the first case, \begin{align*}
1 - 2 \cos(u) &= 0  \\
    \cos u &= \frac{1}{2}  \\
    u &= \pm \arccos\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) + 2 \pi k  \\
      &= \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + 2 \pi k  \text{,} 
\end{align*}
for any integer $k$.  In the second case, \begin{align*}
\sin(u) - 1 &= 0  \\
\sin u &= 1  \\
  u &\in \{\arcsin(1) + 2 \pi k \mid k \in \Bbb{Z} \}  \\
    &\quad {}\cup \{\pi - \arcsin(1) + 2 \pi k \mid k \in \Bbb{Z} \}  \\
    &= \left\{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k \mid k \in \Bbb{Z} \right\}  \\
    &\quad {}\cup \left\{\pi - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k \mid k \in \Bbb{Z} \right\}  \\
    &= \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k  \text{,}
\end{align*}
for any integer $k$.

Now restrict to the interval.

Answer (score -2):

sin u - sin 2u = 1 - 2cos u

we know sin(2x) = 2sinxcosx

substitute u for x:

sin u - 2sin(u)cos(u) = 1 - 2cos(u)

take sin u common,
sin u(1 - 2 cos(u)) = 1 - 2cos(u)

Divide 1 - 2cos(u) on both sides to get your answer :)

(I'm assuming you had to solve for u)

Comment: This methods discards two-thirds of the answers.  In particular, it discards all answers where $1 - 2 \cos(u) = 0$ since you don't account for division by zero.  For instance, $\pi/3$ is a solution to the original equation.